# Link two tables in PowerBI using CSV Ids

Tags: powerbi, azure-table-storage

I have `Post`s that can have one or more associated `Tag`s.

I decided to use Azure Table as Storage for my data, and store the Tag IDs as CSV in the `Tags` column:

```
= Post
PK    RK   Name          Tags
post  321  First Post    003
post  324  Second Post   001,002,003
post  987  Third Post    001,002
post  456  Xth Post      002
...    

= Tag
PK    RK   Name
tag   001  work
tag   002  travel
tag   003  other
```

(PK and RK are Partition and Row Keys respectively in azure tables)

When displaying a report in PowerBI on PostByTags, is there a way link to the `Tag` table by "splitting" the `Tags` column (of the `Post` table) value and linking them to the `RK` column of the `Tag` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the column by delimiter and split the `Post` table into new rows for each tag.

[image: split-1]

[image: split-2]

[image: result]

Then you can have a one-to-many relationship between the two tables and filter the data on the tag field.

[image: relationship]

[image: table]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!